# How to Select Date Coloumn from database using linq in asp.net mvc 5 and compare with current date to print data?

Tags: c#, date

in this case i want to select `Dated` Coloumn From Database then i want to match with the current `date` and then i want to show only those records which match with current `date`.

```
IEnumerable<LocalTeaTbl> GetAllOrbat()
        {
            using (PostOfficeEntities2 db = new PostOfficeEntities2())
            {

                List<LocalTeaTbl> print = db.LocalTeaTbls.Where(x => x.Dated == date).ToList();
                return print;
           }


and `date` is
```

string date = string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", DateTime.Now);

and input format of `date` is same as like above.

Class Definition

```
 public string Dated { get; set; }
```

Comment: What type has `Dated` property?

Comment: i used Date,DateTime and nvarchar and also max(nvarchar) tried everything but no success.

Comment: Getter and Setter are Public, Type String , Nullable (None) , Entity Key False,

Comment: Plz Help i did not get you

Comment: Press [edit] link. Put info about you class definition directly into question.

Comment: i have put class definition in quuestion